# Measure of the coefficients variability for Regularised Regression models

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, standard-deviation, regularization

I am working with Regression models.

My idea is to measure the variability of the coefficients of some Regression models.

I used LOOCV split for the training and testing my dataset.

The following are few rows of my coefficients result associated with each independent variable, and since I used LOOCV and my data has 506 rows, I will get 506 models with their coefficients. At this moment I can average the coefficients and have the standard deviation and other variability measures.

```
                [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]       [,6]      [,7]
      [1,] 0.4833690 -0.2123750 0.10249052 0.008650167 0.05935795 -0.1904433 0.4400553
      [2,] 0.4803859 -0.2129833 0.10221035 0.012684383 0.05947693 -0.1926850 0.4415954
      [3,] 0.4813841 -0.2148075 0.10466271 0.011856752 0.06002647 -0.1917434 0.4401251
      [4,] 0.4812432 -0.2150635 0.10537431 0.013449890 0.05991461 -0.1933659 0.4405225
      [5,] 0.4838644 -0.2157872 0.10701178 0.014210714 0.06007054 -0.1939583 0.4376616
      [6,] 0.4802185 -0.2143879 0.10450493 0.013349886 0.05983871 -0.1924637 0.4424887
      .
      .
      .
```

My question is as follows

If I want to compare the variability (using standard deviation) of the coefficients of the classical regression methods with Lasso and Ridge and Elastic net Regression, how could that be possible? Because I can not calculate the standard deviation from the `glmnet` package.

Any idea is highly appreciated!

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to look at the variance of the coefficients, rather than simply variance of model output.

Comment: @seanv507, yes I am interested in testing changes of coefficients for Leave one out cross-validation (LOOCV). I am not sure what do you mean by the variance of model output!

Comment: see bias-variance decomposition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff. come up with data generating process (ie including noise component), generate sample of data, calculate variance of predictions, repeat for n samples.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the different LOO subsamples are very similar and strongly correlated, and that some instabilities only show up properly if more than one point is left out, (nonparametric) bootstrap is quite certainly better than your LOOCV. Note that there is more than one way of doing bootstrap in regression, which may depend on whether you want to treat your x-values are fixed (and you'd imagine them to be exactly replicated if you replicated your data collection) or random. However, not going into the details of this (it can easily be found in books and on the web googling "regression bootstrap"), standard bootstrap (drawing a random samples of n observations with replacement from your sample) should be an OK thing to do for what you have in mind.

Added after discussion below: For comparing least squares and ridge regression with methods that select variables such as Lasso etc. by empirical standard error and the like, coefficients of variables that were not selected can be set to zero (which is equivalent to not using them, as they are multiplied by their coefficient in most regression models).

Comment: thanks for your time to answer my question. It is ok I can use bootstrapping sampling, but my question is how to compare the variability (using standard deviation) of the coefficients of the classical regression methods with Lasso and Ridge and Elastic net Regression since lasso and elastic net do the vairbale selection??

Comment: A variable that is not selected can be interpreted as having coefficient estimate zero, which can be used for standard error computation.

Comment: what I can see that the comparison with other regression methods is inapplicable since they will have the whole independent variable in the final model. Also, I have no idea how to calculate the standard deviation of lasso and elastic net regression especially using glmnet function.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you saw and understood my previous comment? A variable "not being in the model" is equivalent to having coefficient zero, i.e., multiplying it by zero.Formula for computing the standard error (standard deviation of estimators) doesn't change.  It can be done easily in this way, although it may be somewhat controversial whether this is appropriate. However, if you think it's not, hardly anything can be done.

Comment: many thanks for you. I will also wait for other answers.